# Reduce number of threads in .net console application

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-7.0

**Problem**

I've a .Net7 console application, executed in parallel (many instances of the same program) on a multi-core linux server.
Apparently the server has a limit (ulimit -a) that limits the number of threads created per user. If the application wants to create more threads, an OutOfMemory exception is raised (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/71761).

How to reproduce the issue (on linux/wsl):

```
for (var i = 0; i < int.Parse(args[0]); i++)
{
    var newThread = new Thread(() => Thread.Sleep(10_000));
    newThread.Start();
    if((i+1)%1000 == 0) Console.WriteLine($"Threads: {i+1}");
}
Console.WriteLine("ctrl+c to kill");
```

and run

```
ulimit -u 4096
```

this set the limit to 4096. Then run

```
dotnet run 5000
```

or

```
dotnet run 2500 & dotnet run 2500 &
```

the code will try to create 5000 threads in a single process OR 5000 threads in two processes, but the system has 4096 as limit => OutOfMemory raised in both cases.

Consider to run 100 instances of the program... if the program tries to spawn 40 threads, an OutOfMemory exception is raised.

**Desiderata**

We are trying to increase such limit but I would like to know why so many threads are spawned (let's use #ObsTh = `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Length`).
Info:

- it's a .Net7 console application, published in Release mode, linux-x64, standalone
- the app does not start threads itself, it just uses async/await paradigm. first line of code in top level statment: #ObsTh=10 threads
- the app perform few HttpClient.GetAsync() requests. The `HttpClient` is retrieved from `IHttpClientFactory` registered in the `ServiceCollection`. #ObsTh=22 threads (+12)
- the app uses `StackExchange.Redis`. After connection, #ObsTh=32 threads (+10) in a dedicatedthreadpool.
- sometimes the thread count reaches 35-40 threads and my application is "basically" a single thread application.

now... Excluding `StackExchange.Redis` (but if you know something let me know), how can I reduce the number of threads in my console app?

---

Just few lines of codes that shows the behavior (I'm excluding redis):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1, 1);

Console.WriteLine($"Start process: {Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count}");

HttpClient c = new HttpClient();
var result = await c.GetAsync("https://www.bing.com");
result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine($"After http call: {Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count}");
```

If I run this program.cs with `dotnet run` (or after publish run) the result is:

```
Start process: 8
After http call: 22
```

so... just after few lines of code I have 8 threads, after httpcall 22. I just would like to reduce this number (if possible) because I'm running a lot of instances of this program.

---

**Keep in mind**: the problem is that **linux has a limit and I have to reduce the amount of threads used by my app. No problems on windows or if I increase linux limit**.
An instance of my application now runs for about 30-40 seconds:

- Time spent for http calls: ~0.5 seconds
- Time spent reading data from redis: ~3 seconds.
- The remaining time is on CPU.

Rider, using above code, shows:

- 3 Unknown ?
- 3 ThreadPool Workers
- 1 ThreadPool Wait
- 1 ThreadPool IO
- 1 ThreadPool Gate
- 1 .NET Timer
- 1 Main Thread

- How to see the other 26-11=15 threads? and, more important, how to reduce them?

Comment: OOMs are typically caused by inefficient coding, not multiple threads. Adding lots of items to a list one by one can lead to such memory fragmentation that the runtime can't find a single contiguous memory chunk to reallocate the list's buffer once it's full. Limiting the threads will only delay the problem

Comment: Post your code, don't assume this is about threads. `async/await` uses threads from a threadpool which can *easily* handle 1000 threads without problems.

Comment: I'm able to reprodure "OutOfMemoryException" just creating manually 4096+ threads in a linux machine with "ulimit -u = 4096" . Today we've increased this limit to 16384 and the OutOfMemoryException is raised after 16k+ threads created.

Comment: And I can reproduce that with 1 thread, by allocating 1MB arrays in a tight loop. On the other hand, trying 4K concurrent *sockets* could cause networking problems on most machines. Contrived bad code can always cause crashes. Why would a normal application end up with 4K threadpool threads in the first place? Those are meant to be *reused*. Which means the application is *blocking* them

Comment: In any case, you haven't posted anything that demonstrates or reproduces the problem. If the snippet you posted is called concurrently, it's leaking sockets. HttpClient is thread-safe and *meant* to be reused and handles a socket pool itself. The OS itself pools sockets because establishing them is expensive. This is well known: [You're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: Be sure to distinguish ThreadPool.ThreadCount from Process.Threads.  The latter also counts threads that don't execute any managed code.  Such as any native threads used to service those GetAsync() calls.  The more likely source, the code as shown doesn't put any load on the threadpool.  Use an unmanaged debugger to see what they do.

Answer (score 2):

Most of those are going to be thread pool threads, so `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` is your friend. .NET has historically targeted desktop/server environments with the intention of using the available computing resources, so targeting restrained execution environments does require tweaking.

Comment: There's no reason to assume that just 40 threads will cause an OOM, when the threadpool limit is 1000 since 4.6  if not earlier. Something else is going on. There shouldn't even be 40 threads unless something is blocking them

Comment: I've added few lines of codes. Even with ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1, 1); after an http get I have 20+ threads running.

Comment: @Sierrodc those few lines leak sockets and HttpClient instances if executed concurrently

Answer (score 0):

A partial response.

I was not able to reduce threads spawned by .net (and threading pool) using `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`.

It is possible to configure `StackExchange.Redis` to use threads in the ThreadPool and not a dedicated pool of threads (that is composed by 10 threads):

```
    var configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
    {
        SocketManager = SocketManager.ThreadPool
    };
```

So, I was able to reduce by 8 threads.